# How to sort a TrackableCollection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework 'TrackableCollection' and I want to sort it by an attribute.  I have tried treating it like an IEnumerable and calling

```
TrackableCollection<Something>.OrderBy(q=>q.SomeValue);
```

but it throws an exception "Cannot implicitly covert type IOrderedEnumerable to TrackableCollection.

Anyone know how to sort a TrackableCollection?

Answer (score 3):

The code example Shiv Kumar refers to does not work - it doesn't compile, and even after you factor things up (like implementing generics in a lot of places), it works but buggy, since the code calls collection.Move which causes a "Index must be within the bounds of the List" exception in certain cases.
The code below works correctly. The coders of STE (Self Tracking Entities) should had implemented that themselves... This is the correct code:

```
    public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Sort<T>(this TrackableCollection<T> collection, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        var comparer = new Comparer<T>(comparison);
        List<T> sorted = collection.OrderBy(x=>x, comparer) .ToList();

        collection.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
            collection.Add(sorted[i]);
    }
}

class Comparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private Comparison<T> comparison;
    public Comparer(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return comparison.Invoke(x, y);
    }
}
```

You use this code as in the previous example:

```
YourTrackableCollectionName.Sort((x, y) => x.YourFieldName.CompareTo(y.YourFieldName));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplifed version of Ofer Zeligs code that uses a keySelector func (like LINQ `OrderBy`) instead of an explicit `Comparison` delegate. Since it only uses Clear() and Add() it can be called on any `Collection` object (like an `ObservableCollection` or a `TrackableCollection`).

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this Collection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var sorted = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();

    source.Clear();
    foreach (var item in sorted)
        source.Add(item);
}
```

It's used like this:

```
list.Sort(person => person.Name);
```

If you're using this on a `TrackableCollection` (STE) you might want to make sure you haven't started tracking changes before sorting the list.